# Create instance of a variable in another class

Tags: java

i have this code:

```
File fileData = new File(this.getDataFolder(), "data.yml");
    FileConfiguration data = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(fileData);
    data.options().copyDefaults(true);
    try {
        data.save(fileData);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

now my question is how i can do a instance of data in other class, i mean this is bukkit so i need that in another class i can execute the command data.save(fileData);

Comment: If you want the same data object then pass it as a parameter to another class's method. If you want a new instance, then do what you are doing here in another class

Comment: i dont really understand how , i am really a newbie , this file is in the onEnable method is overrided

Answer (score 0):

If you need that specific instance of FileConfiguration, the only way to have its reference in another class is using constructors, assuming the other class where you need this object is created in this class you could do something like so:

```
class YourClass{
    File fileData;
    FileConfiguration data;

    @Override
    void onEnable(){
        fileData = new File(this.getDataFolder(), "data.yml");
        data = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(fileData);
        data.options().copyDefaults(true);
        try {
            data.save(fileData);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void theMethodWhereYouInstantiateTheOtherClass(){
        OtherClass oc = new OtherClass();
    }
}
```

And the the other class would look something like:

```
class OtherClass{
    FileConfiguration data;

    public OtherClass(FileConfiguration data){
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```